# Missing dependency error in an angular application

Tags: angular, angular-social-login

I am trying to create a social login app using angular. When I try to run my angular application I getting the following error and also I am not able to access the login page.

ERROR in The target entry-point

> "angular-6-social-login" has missing dependencies:
>    - @angular/core
>    - @angular/common
>    - rxjs

Comment: reinstall packages using `npm install`

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove `package-lock` and `node_modules`. After reinstall them

Answer (score 0):

The error message has your solution.

angular-6-social-login requires libraries which your project does not have. Going through its repo, you can see the dependencies it declares [here](https://github.com/high54/angular-6-social-login/blob/master/package.json).

Both `@angular/core` and `@angular/common` should not need to be added explicitly though. Which makes me think the files have either been deleted, or the versions installed are different than the ones needed.

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/login-with-facebook-and-google-using-angular-8.  I have used this tutorial I am not able to run with any of your suggestions. let me what best I can do

Comment: Ok. Can you post the contents of package.json file in the question ?

Comment: Looks good. Re-installing the packages should work in this case. Run npm install and try.